# How to set transparent background for RadioButton in API 16?

Tags: android, radio-button

I've a radio button with a custom background for it's different states. To use this background I set the `android:button` attribute to `transparent`. It seems this was not (yet) supported back in API 16 and the background appears only black.

How can I achieve the same effect as in API 17 and above?

radio_button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/grey"/>
      <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/grey"/>
      <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/grey"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:padding="8dp"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Your choice"
      android:textSize="12sp"/>

  <RadioGroup
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Easy"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Middle"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hard"/>

  </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshot API 16**

[image]

**Screenshot API 17**

[image]

Comment: Try to set `<solid android:color="#00000000"/>` to the shape of your third `<item>` in drawable background and remove `android:button` attribute. I suggest using your custom colours as practice shows android colours can be different from device to device.

Comment: This works, thanks! There is a side effect though that when I click a RadioButton its background turns grey but never leaves this state anymore. Any hint on this?

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu you can post your comment as answer. It works to solve my problem. The side effect I had was caused because I didn't add an `android:id` attribute on the RadioButton's. Adding the id resolves this.

Comment: Glad it worked! Answer posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `<solid android:color="#00000000"/>` to the shape of your third `<item>` in the drawable background and remove `android:button` attribute from `AppCompatRadioButton`s. I suggest using your custom colours as practice shows android colours can be different from device to device.

Comment: Ok, I've an update. The `shape` item in the selector file will actually inflate as `ShapeDrawable` which extends `Drawable`. I assume that in API 16 `Drawable` does set a different default background color (which would be the `solid` color in the XML). I couldn't proof it to myself by inspecting Android source code though. I also didn't remove the `android:button` attribute of the radio button. Because this removes the actual RadioButton circle and this is also something I want.

Comment: Ah and I also use `<solid android:color="android:color/transparent"/>` instead of `<solid android:color="#00000000"/>`